# How this Inner class inheritance example works?

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

I was reading about inheritance from inner classes and I got stuck trying to understand how the code below works:

```
class Outer{
    class Inner{
    }
}
class Derived extends Outer.Inner{
    Derived(Outer o){
        o.super();
    }
}
```

As far as I know, the keyword super refers to the superclass, super() to it's no argument constructor. In case of Outer class, the superclass is Object class. 
I would like to understand, how this code works. 
Why instantiation of Object class makes extending Inner class possible? 
What creating an Object class instance has to do with creating Outer class object?

Removing line containing "o.super();" cause error: 
java: an enclosing instance that contains p.Outer.Inner is required

I read many articles but I can't figure out how it works.
I will be greatful for any answer.

Comment: Test it out. Put println() lines in all the constructors and watch in what order it prints them out. ;)

Comment: If you do this in a real project, you might want to rethink your object hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a variable `o` referring to an instance of `Outer`, and you want to create an instance of `Inner` with its enclosing instance being the value of `o`. You could call:

```
Outer.Inner inner = o.new Outer.Inner();
```

It's rarely seen in Java (because usually when you construct an inner class, you do it with "this" being the implicit enclosing instance), but it's valid.

This is really the equivalent of that, but in the context of a subclass constructor. The `Inner` class *really* has a constructor like this:

```
Inner(Outer enclosingInstance)
```

... and this line is *effectively* calling

```
super(o)
```

... it's just it's not expressed that way in syntax to differentiate between this "special" information and any regular parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> Why instantiation of Object class makes extending Inner class possible?

In Inner instance need an Outer instance to be an inner instance of. it doesn't make sense to have it without it's outer instance.  If it did make sense to have an Inner without an Outer you would make it `static`

> What creating an Object class instance has to do with creating Outer class object?

You need an Outer instance before you can create an Inner instance.

> I read many articles but I can't figure out how it works.

It sets the `Outer` instance the `Inner` super-class needs.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Inner` is called a nested inner class and is binded to the Outer class in such a way that for initializing it is required to use an instance of the Outer class like this `Outer.Inner inner = (new Outer()).new Inner();`

If your inner class were declared using the static modifier, it would be a static nested class and no instance of the Outer class would be required for initializing a new instance of it, like this: `Outer.Inner inner = new Outer.Inner();`

Answer (score 0):

you instantiate the inner class like this `Outer outer = new Outer(); Inner inner = outer.new Inner();`